# Prevent Excel file download but allow read

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have uploaded an excel sheet to SharePoint 2013 document library.

We can click on this file and it opens in xlviewer.aspx page

We can also enter the url as `http://sharepointsite/shared documents/docname.xls` and the file will get downloaded.

Is there any way in which we can prevent download but allow users to view the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to put the excel sheet as a excel services webpart on a SharePoint site page.

Comment: Can this be done when opening the documents from document library(xlviewer.aspx page)

Comment: Ideally you should not allow users to view the entire document library.. However, it depends on your requirements..